# How to change the region of AWS at runtime using iOS sdk?

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

Thanks in advance.
I'm planning to release an app in different countries,
where the users will be given an option to select the country and based on the selection their respective aws region will be used.

First time login works fine, where the user selects the region and S3 upload works fine.

But If the user signs out and then another user logs in with different region, then the s3 upload fails with time out error.

Here is the code:

```
guard let config = AWSServiceConfiguration(region: regionTypeByString(regionString: userData.getS3RegionBasedOnSelection()), credentialsProvider: self.awsAuthenticationProvider) else { return }
AWSS3TransferUtility.register(with: config, forKey: "Transfer")

AWSS3TransferUtility.s3TransferUtility(forKey: "Transfer")?.uploadFile(
                fileUrl,
                bucket: bucketPath,
                key: key,
                contentType: "application/octet-stream",
                expression: expression,
                completionHandler: { (task, error) in

                    if error != nil {
                        DDLogInfo("!!!!!! Error RAW: \(String(describing: error))")
                        DDLogInfo("!!!!!! Error Code: \(error!.code)")
                        DDLogInfo("!!!!!! Error Description: \(error!.localizedDescription)")
                    }
                })
```

What's the proper way to change/switch s3 region ?

Answer (score 1):

For each region create a config and register it under respective keys.
And do the same while initializing the AWSS3.

eg:

region1:

```
let config = AWSServiceConfiguration(region: .USWest1, credentialsProvider: getAwsAuthenticationProvider())
AWSS3.register(with: config, forKey: "USWest1")
AWSS3TransferUtility.register(with: config, forKey: "USWest1")
//--> later in code
    let transferUtility = AWSS3TransferUtility.s3TransferUtility(forKey: "USWest1")
    transferUtility.uploadFile ()
```

region2:

```
let config = AWSServiceConfiguration(region: .USWest2, credentialsProvider: getAwsAuthenticationProvider())
AWSS3.register(with: config, forKey: "USWest2")
AWSS3TransferUtility.register(with: config, forKey: "USWest2")
//--> later in code
     let transferUtility = AWSS3TransferUtility.s3TransferUtility(forKey: "USWest2")
     transferUtility.uploadFile ()
```